# How to figure out if a circle is inside a sector?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I am creating a program which plots circles (blips) in a sector (of a circle) all of the blips are inside the sector, however, some are protruding outside of the sector (the origin of the blip is still inside).

How do I figure out if a circle is fully inside a sector? I've looked around everywhere and the only answers I've found are for a point in a sector *NOT* a circle.

All the values are provided; the sector radius ($r_0$), origin ($x_0, y_0$), angle, the blips each have origin coordinates ($x_b,y_b$) and a radius ($r_b$).

Blips coordinates are randomly calculated using the following formulas (maybe there's an adjust that could be made to account for the blip radius?):

- $x_b = x_0 + r_0\sin(\theta)$
- $y_b = y_0 + r_0\cos(\theta)$
- $\theta$ is randomly selected as an angle between the start of the sector and the end of a sector.

[The green are all valid, the red should be detected as outside the sector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfC5C.png)

Comment: Is the blip centre outside the big circle? Is the blip centre too close to the boundary of the  big circle?  Is the blip centre outside the sector angle? Does the blip intersect either of the two radii?  If not, the blip should be inside the sector

Comment: Hint: Try drawing the region, where it is valid to place the small circles. What kind of region is it?